# Why after login user keeps both roles guest and user in yii2?

Tags: yii2

i'm using rbac in yii2 project. When i print

```
var_dump(\Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->id));
```

I get an array with two elements: guest and user?
Why "guest" role stays at authorized user? Is it normal behavior or I did something wrong?

Comment: Do you have guest in `Yii::$app->authManager->defaultRoles`?

Comment: Yes, i do. After user logined i want only "user" role to be left in Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. If you add some role to `defaultRoles`, it will be always available, regardless of authentication state. From [`$defaultRoles`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rbac-basemanager#$defaultRoles-detail) docs:

> A list of role names that are assigned to every user automatically without calling assign(). Note that these roles are applied to users, regardless of their state of authentication.

Comment: And there is no way to remove defaultRoles from user, after he logined?

Comment: @RuslanNasrutdinov No, see this issue: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12806 . You need to use [rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-rules) if you want to make it more dynamic depending on context.